# Phone state listener always executes code

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-state-listener

I have set `phoneStateListener` in my app which turns the phone silent when the phone is turned upside down during an incoming call. The problem is that the phone gets silent irrespective of any condition. Here is my code-

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch (state) {
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // callStateStr = "ringing. Incoming number is: "
                // + incomingNumber;

                if (z1 > -10 && z1 < -9) {//this is to detect if the phone is turned upside down or not. consider this defined.

                    am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0,
                            AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES);
                    Log.d("abc", "turning silent");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "turning silent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
}
}
};
```

During an incoming call, the code under `if` condition is executed whether i turn my phone or not.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other method to achieve this purpose?

Comment: Where do you get `z1`? Wouldn't this code be better placed in the `onSensorChanged` callback?

Comment: @323go- This code is inside `onSensorChanged` callback only. And `z1` is z-axis value of the `SensorEvent`. I have avoided some codes to make the code look tidy.

Comment: @323go Should i post the whole code?